# Make page height 100% of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have this page as part of a website based on a wordpress theme:

http://www.coveburgess.com/post-test-1/

Im trying to make the whole page & slider 100% of the browser height so that when the screen gets smaller, the slider resizes rather than crops - and preferably only on the 'post' pages and not on the rest of the website.

I have played with the CSS for a while now (I'm very a beginner at css etc.), setting different containers at 100% including:

```
html {height: 100%;}
```

but none of it has worked so far.

Many thanks for any help
Tom

Comment: **height: 100vh;** will do it

Comment: I think you might have to set it on body instead of html. If you're going to use 100%, you probably need it on both, but if you use 100vh, probably only the body. This is untested, which is why I'm commenting instead of answering.

Answer (score 6):

it’s only compatible with newer browsers.
`.section-full {height:100vh;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JQ

```
var sectionFull = $('.section-full');
var windH = $(window).height();

sectionFull.css({
   height: windH
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    sectionFull.css({
        height: windH
    });
});
```